# Is there an Iterator-like trait which returns references that must fall out of scope before the next access?

Tags: iterator, rust, mutable

This would make it possible to safely iterate over the same element twice, or to hold some state for the global thing being iterated over in the item type.

Something like:

```
trait IterShort<Iter>
    where Self: Borrow<Iter>,
{
    type Item;

    fn next(self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}
```

then an implementation could look like:

```
impl<'a, MyIter> IterShort<MyIter> for &'a mut MyIter {
    type Item = &'a mut MyItem;

    fn next(self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I realize I could write my own (I just did), but I'd like one that works with the `for`-loop notation. Is that possible?

Comment: Not one that works with `for`. Using a little setup and a `while let` might be nice enough, though.

Comment: This is sometimes called a *streaming iterator* and it has many more applications. (Your example trait does not do that though. I'm not sure what it does but it looks strange.). But, as Veedrac said, no language support.

Answer (score 2):

The standard iterators can't do this as far as I can see. The very definition of an iterator is that the outside has control over the elements while the inside has control over what produces the elements.

From what I understand of what you are trying to do, I'd flip the concept around and instead of returning elements from an iterator to a surrounding environment, pass the environment to the iterator. That is, you create a struct with a constructor function that accepts a closure and implements the iterator trait. On each call to `next`, the passed-in closure is called with the next element and the return value of that closure or modifications thereof are returned as the current element. That way, `next` can handle the lifetime of whatever would otherwise be returned to the surrounding environment.

Comment: Suppose you're passing a &[u8] to this closure though, and the slice is invalidated between calls to the closure. Aren't we back at the original problem again? How do we give a lifetime to &[u8] such that it's only valid for the duration of the function call, and can't have a reference saved by the closure?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=14a2eacbfeecd5e946ea074f5c5362d0

Answer (score 2):

The `std::iter::Iterator` trait can not do this, but you can write a different trait:

```
trait StreamingIterator {
    type Item;
    fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a mut Self::Item>;
}
```

Note that the return value of `next` borrows the iterator itself, whereas in `Vec::iter` for example it only borrows the vector.

The downside is that `&mut` is hard-coded. Making it generic would require higher-kinded types (so that `StreamingIterator::Item` could itself be generic over a lifetime parameter).

Alexis Beingessner gave a talk about this and more titled *Who Owns This Stream of Data?* at [RustCamp](http://rustcamp.com/schedule.html).

As to `for` loops, they’re really tied to `std::iter::IntoIterator` which is tied to `std::iter::Iterator`. You’d just have to implement both.

Comment: Isn't the return value valid as long as the iterator though? How do you get the return value to be valid only until the next call to next()?